# Ruby: How to restrict some elements of a struct to certain values and make some elements mandatory during XMl parsing

Tags: ruby, xml, excel, struct

I have created a struct that will store some information I parse from XML using Nokogiri and some information that is entered after the struct is exported to Excel and users edit the 'spec'.  The information I require to be in the XML is the first attribute through :type and the other is the information users will edit after export to Excel.

```
class Spec < Struct.new(
:trace-id,
:ip-pdm,    # exact IP name
:ip,        # human consumable IP name 
:parameter,
:symbol,
:min,
:max,
:typ,
:unit,
:notes,
:type,
:guaranteed-by, # acceptable values are 'ATE','BENCH','PROXY','DESIGN','CONSTRUCTION','SIMULATION'
:en-gate,
:en-final_test,
:en-probe,
:un-testable,
:disposition-required,
:pe-notes,
:te-notes,
:de-notes,
:qa-notes,
:ate-limits_reversed,
:last_revised );
```

The second part of my question is if it is possible to pre-define the valid values for certain elements like :guaranteed-by.  As you can see by the code comment we only want certain values to be entered when users enter data.  general users will eneter data in excel but some super-users may create the structs via Ruby.

thx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well, it can be done using an XSD schema to validate xml data.
A quick search give this page about the library your using:

http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Schema.html

Comment: Is it possible for you to give a sample code as per your instruction? If you do, it will make your answer more nice. I will wait for the same from you.

Comment: yes i plan to use the schema validation so OK i guess that solves the first part of my question thanks.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I don't know Ruby, my answer comes from xml knowledge, but I don't know how to implement it in ruby, I'm a .Net developer. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Not with Structs, but you can use for example [virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) gem in order to create some basic models with validations.

Comment: what if i used HappyMapper instead of a struct?  class User
  include HappyMapper
  
  element :id, Integer
  element :name, String
  element :screen_name, String
  element :location, String
  element :description, String
  element :profile_image_url, String
  element :url, String
  element :protected, Boolean
  element :followers_count, Integer
end

Comment: I can't see this being able to perform validation. You'd have to implement this.